# How to use MS Sync framework with visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-sync-framework

I am developing an OCA Windows form application with C# .net 4.5 on Visual studio 2013.

I was looking for "how to sync" my local database with a central database; and I got Microsoft Sync framework. But all tutorials and blogs pinpoint visual studio 20110 and MS SQL Server 2008. That is quite old now.

I followed this [article](http://mentormate.com/blog/database-synchronization-with-microsoft-sync-framework/). But in Visual Studio 2013 Local Database Cache is not supported. I don't know how can I use MS Sync framework with visual studio 2013

Please provide any solution that works for sync in visual studio 2013 with MS SQL server 2012 Express.

Answer (score 1):

The Local Database Cache project item was removed from VS 2013 but there's no stopping you downloading the SDK and coding the Sync stuff yourself. The SDK documentation itself has walkthroughs on how to do the sync.

Comment: Can you provide any link for this ?

Comment: a quick search would have netted you this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=23217